# Print a square of * (asterisks) with Unix

Tags: bash, unix, sh

First of all, sorry if my English isn't very good, but it isn't my primary language (edited).

I'm self-learning to script on Unix, and I'm trying to make an script that asks for a number and then prints a square out of the given number, for example:

```
Size of square?
4
```

```sh
****
****
****
****
```

But I can't get it to print more than a single `*` (asterisk) character per line.

This is my code right now:

```sh
echo "Size of the square?"
    read size

clear

for (( i=0;i<size;i++ ))            
do
    echo "*"
done
```

I'm trying to make it work, and tried to use 2 for loops, but I just can't make it work.

Answer (score 1):

`echo` prints a new line at the end, use `printf` instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Size of the square?"
    read size

clear

for (( i=0; i<$size; i++ )); do
    for (( j=0; j<$size; j++ )); do
        printf "*"
    done
    printf "\n"
done
```

Comment: Could also use `echo -n` which doesn't print newlines.

Answer (score 1):

### you can also try out this one

1. size 4

it will show

```
{****
*  *
*  *
****}
```

```
echo "enter the sizeof the square"
read size
clear
for (( i = 1; i <= size; i++ )); do
    for (( j = 1; j <= size; j++ )); do

        if [ "$i" == 1 ] || [ "$i" == "$size" ] || [ "$j" == 1 ] || [ "$j" == "$size" ]
         then
            #statements
            tput cup $i $j
            echo "*"
        fi
     done
done
```